# How to perform mathematical operation on data from CSV File?

Tags: php, mysql, csv, phpmyadmin, fgetcsv

I've csv file with 125 columns

Indicative 125 columns are : 
ROLL_NO, SCHOOL_ID, NAME, STANDARD, SOURCE_ID, Q1,Q2,Q3 (this continues upto) Q120

CSV file is having around 20,0000 records (For various Schools)

I want to calculate perform some mathematical operations on the data present in CSV file. Expected operations are :

- Find Average
- Find Maximum Marks (for each school)
- Summation of data of specific column

Currently I'm planning to load this CSV in Database and perform required operation ; I've few questions before getting started;

- Is there any alternate approach to perform maths operation using PHP (without loading in DB)
- How to store columns in csv as rows in Database table (from Q1 to Q120)

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to load into a spreadsheet and then do all the maths? If this is a frequent task you could also set up some macros to do the whole thing for you.

Comment: @jeff thanks for the suggestion, csv data manupulation is one of the step of automated process ; so unfortunately I'll not be able to work manually into a spreadsheet ...

Answer (score 1):

Since CSV is a plain text files with no indexes whatsoever, any operation on it requires at least one full read of the file. If you have enough RAM, you can read the file into arrays into PHP and perform the operations in-memory, which will be slightly faster if you are performing multiple operations in a row.

However, if you plan to do more serious computations, I'd urge you to load the data into a database with indexes, such as MySQL, where you can perform such operations a lot faster.

Comment: In my csv I've 120 question Q1 to Q120 ; i want to perform some operation on this data, is there any recommendation to break data of CSV into two tables: 1) Table 1 to store first five fields 2) Table 2 with 120 questions stored with roll number ?

Answer (score 1):

is this what you want? this can be automated.

### 1. split csv to two files

with `awk` or `cut`, you can split by column.

tbl1.csv will contain data from column1 to column5
tbl2.csv will contain data column1 (ROLL_NO) and from column6 to column 125

```
$ cut -d "," -f1-5 input.csv > tbl1.csv
$ cut -d "," -f1,6-120 input.csv > tbl2.csv
```

### 2. load csv to table using `LOAD DATA`

I assume you already know about `LOAD DATA`

be careful with escaping ',' in data. CSV has no standard way about escaping. If you csv has only digit number, escaping may not be a problem.